# A VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) data type column displayed as blank

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I had been doing a simple select statement to print some columns with data type VARCHAR2(20 BYTE). But they are displayed as blank. The field is supposed to have the value "000002018151000709" or similar.I am not sure why the value is not displayed in select. I am running this from oracle SQL Developer.

Example : Both id fields are float and accession is VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

Query 1 :

```
SELECT aor.accession_id,aor.accession,o.order_id

from orders o

left outer join accession_order_r aor on aor.order_id = o.ORDER_ID
                                and aor.accession != null

where o.CATALOG_TYPE_CD = 123 --lab
  and o.UPDT_DT_TM >= TO_DATE('2019-06-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  and o.UPDT_DT_TM <= TO_DATE('2019-06-01 01:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
--and aor.accession_id = 55260.00
  and o.order_id = 91683.00
```

Query 2:

```
select * from accession a
join accession_order_r ar on a.accession_id = ar.accession_id

where a.accession_id = 55260.00
```

Query 1 returns a blank accession and still returns an order_id,if I query on order_id. But if I use accession_id it returns NULL.

Query 2 returns all the values and works correctly.

Comment: Please share the DDL of the table. How you inserted the data and how you are accessing the data. Share your query too.

Comment: I have not inserted any data. Its a production data base and we have 2 ways of accessing that database.So I am using a simple select statement using sql developer (select * from table_name). I am running the other query from Cerner Query on the same data base and I can see the value.

Comment: Try running the `SELECT <ISSUE COLUMN NAME> FROM TABLE WHERE..` in SQL*Plus.(If you have access)
And Try running the `SELECT LENGTH(<ISSUE COLUMN NAME>) FROM TABLE WHERE..` in Sql Developer

Comment: Another option is to run `select dump(the_column) from the_table where ...` to see if there are any "special" characters in that column.

Comment: If I use DUMP , it gives me the value as NULL.
      SELECT LENGTH(<ISSUE COLUMN NAME>) FROM TABLE WHERE..  If I run this I get blank column. I also tried                               case when aor.accession = NULL
  then 'yes'
  else
  'no'
end as acc And this always prints a no

Comment: Query 1 and Query 2 are returning different results because Query 1 uses a `LEFT OUTER` join while Query 2 is an inner join. Query 1 will show `o.order_id` values even when there is no matching `aor` record based on the join condition, hence the rows with `order_id` and blanks elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Tad. But the values did exist so even if it was a left join they should have been displayed.@a_horse_with_no_name said the right thing below, and its because of NULL Condition.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the below condition and everything seemed to work, which I am not sure why. Please update the answer if anyone knows the reason for this. Thanks for your help.

```
  and aor.accession != null
```

Comment: If you want to return only not NULL values, you need to use `and accession IS NOT NULL`. Neither `=` nor `<>` will work with NULL values.